# Firebase Phone Auth Returning getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzao@5a11a93

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

When i click in get otp in mobile i am getting

```
I/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzao@5a11a93
```

My App Gredle file is

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.2.1'
implementation 'com.chaos.view:pinview:1.3.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
implementation "com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.0.0"
implementation "com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:6.0.2"
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.1'
implementation 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.5@aar'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

My Project Gredle file is

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()   
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()  
}
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And my gredle.properties is

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

i am unable to get otp
I have runed through mobile
can u please helpme to get out of this

Comment: I got this error while there was no internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

Have you add Google Plugin..?

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-service
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error while there was no internet connection.